# Taking snapshot of AGSMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, arcgis

Using following code to take snapshot of AGSMapView

This code will set the kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking property, its needed else it will take white snapshot.

```
let layer =  self.AgsMapView.layer as! CAEAGLLayer
        layer.drawableProperties = [
            kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking: NSNumber(int: 1),                                      kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8]
```

Code to take snapshot

```
func snapshotForEAGLView() -> UIImage {

        //glFlush()
        var width: GLint = 0, height: GLint = 0
        let scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        let prevGLContext = EAGLContext.currentContext()
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH), &width)
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT), &height)

        let dataLength = width * height * 4
        let imageBytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.alloc(Int(dataLength))

        glPixelStorei(GLenum(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT), 4)

        glReadPixels(0, 0, GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), imageBytes)

        let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, imageBytes, Int(dataLength), nil)

        EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(prevGLContext)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        if let imageRef = CGImageCreate(Int(width), Int(height), 8, 32, Int(width) * 4, colorSpace, [CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big, CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)], dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault) {
            return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: scale, orientation: .DownMirrored)
        }
        return UIImage()
    }
```

In app we have `AGSMapView` on two controllers, lets say `Controller1` and `Controller2`, on click of button on `Controller1`, `Controller2` is pushed.

We are taking screenshot on `Controller2`, but sometime it takes screenshot of AGSMapView from `Controller1`

It occurs randomly, is there any way in which we can provide which view to take screenshot or any other way to avoid this.

Any help really appreciated thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> drawViewHierarchyInRect

worked, thanks every one

```
    let size = CGSizeMake(viewWidth, viewHeight)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    let rec = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight)
    self.agsMapView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(rec, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
```